# RxJs special filtering

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have this piece of typescript code which is calling a web service and then selectively (based on type) appends the received menu items in an array of root menu items :

```
private loadMenuItems() {
  this.menuService.getAll().subscribe(menuItems => {

    this.rootMenus.forEach(rootMenu => {
      rootMenu.menus = menuItems
          .filter(menuItem => menuItem.type === rootMenu.rootMenu.type)
          .sort((a, b) => a.showOrder - b.showOrder);

          this.menuItems.concat(rootMenu.menus);
      }, this.errorCallback);

  });
}
```

i would like instead of subscribing the observable in this method that it would return the observable with these data already in shape.

How could i do this ?

Comment: `return this.menuService.getAll().pipe(...)`?

Comment: Just map instead of subscribe

Comment: Is the errorCallback placed at the wrong place? It's a second argument to forEach now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pipe it into a `map` (and `catchError` for the errorCallback). Assuming you misplaced the errorCallback, this is how you would do it:

```
private loadMenuItems() {
  return this.menuService.getAll().pipe(map(menuItems => {

    this.rootMenus.forEach(rootMenu => {
      rootMenu.menus = menuItems
          .filter(menuItem => menuItem.type === rootMenu.rootMenu.type)
          .sort((a, b) => a.showOrder - b.showOrder);

          this.menuItems.concat(rootMenu.menus);
      });

  }), catchError(this.errorCallback));
}
```